# redirecting traffic from a network interface to dansguardian

Tags: networking, ubuntu-12.04, iptables

I have setup a Squid + Dansguardian parental control at home. I connected a WIFI router to the Ubuntu machine and share that network for my kids' mobile devices. The parental control works fine on the box and I have used IPTables to route ALL http traffic to dansguardian. For some reason, when I route the eth0 (the shared network) to dansguardian (port 8080), it does not work. It works fine if I route it to squid (port 3128), it works fine ( ofcourse without dansguardian filtering).

This is how I have my iptables right now (routing eth0 to 3128) :

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 3128

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ! owner UID match proxy tcp dpt:http redir ports 8080
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:3128 owner UID match proxy

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  10.42.0.0/24        !10.42.0.0/24
```

but the moment i route the eth0 over to 8080 (instead of 3128 in PREROUTING), I am not able to access the internet. Not sure what is going wrong . Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the problem, I had the dansguardian started on 127.0.0.1 and was not running oon all the available IPs. removed the 127.0.0.1 from the conf and it all works fine now.